# How do I convert css clip rect() to clipPath?

Tags: css, clip, clip-path

I have some older code that uses CSS clip. It still works very well but since clip is deprecated I want to switch to using clipPath. The docs sounded like using inset() with the same *top right bottom left* properties would work, but it doesn't produce the same result. Here's an example:

```
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/0qG5Bzp/stone-wall.jpg" style="position: absolute; height: 554px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 2216px; clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 25px); border: 1px solid red;">

<img src="https://i.ibb.co/0qG5Bzp/stone-wall.jpg" style="position: absolute; height: 554px; top: 125px; left: 0px; width: 2216px; clip-path: inset(0px 50px 100px 25px);  border: 1px solid red;">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/39742zoh/

I've searched Google for some time and while there's a lot of good information on how to use clipPath, there's not any information on converting your old clip code to the newer clipPath property.

How would I produce the same clip using clipPath?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *but it doesn't produce the same result* --> show us

Comment: Apologies. Example and JSFiddle posted.

Comment: there is no comma for inset()

Comment: Thanks. I removed the commas and it's still not the same. Updated the question and the fiddle to reflect the change.

Comment: That's what my question states: I read the documentation for each one and they both appear to use the same top/right/bottom/left variables but the end result is different.

Comment: *The <top> and <bottom> values are offsets from the inside top border edge of the box, while* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"top" and "bottom" for `rect()` consider the top border as a reference which is different with `inset()` because for the latter "bottom" will consider the bottom border as a reference. Same logic for "left" and "right"

You need to do the following to get the same result

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/0qG5Bzp/stone-wall.jpg" style="position: absolute; height: 554px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 2216px; clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 25px); border: 1px solid red;">

<img src="https://i.ibb.co/0qG5Bzp/stone-wall.jpg" style="position: absolute; height: 554px; top: 125px; left: 0px; width: 2216px; clip-path: inset(0px calc(100% - 50px) calc(100% - 100px) 25px);  border: 1px solid red;">
```

```
clip: rect(top, right, bottom, left);
```

```
clip-path: inset(top calc(100% - right) calc(100% - bottom) left)
```